# My for loop fails to check correctly if there is a 0 or a 1 in an array

Tags: java, arrays, loops, methods

So I have gotten this assignment, where we have to check create an array and fill it with `0`s and `1`s. Now, the purpose of the program is to find how many `1`s are in the array, so the output should be the number of `1`s.

I have thus created a method, that searches the array in hot pursuit of the `1`s, but somehow fails to find them. I have checked through eclipse and the input numbers are assigned correctly into the array, but somehow, the method fails to find the dreaded `1`s.

```
public static int finding1s (int array[][]){
    for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++){
        for ( int j =0; j < array[i].length; j++){
             if (array[i][j] != 0){
                value++;
            }
        }
    }
    return value;
}
```

So for instance, if the input of the two dimensions of the array are 5 and 4, and the numbers assigned in the array to their respective integers are

```
0100  
1000  
0010  
1101  
1111
```

the method will not output `10` as it should because there are `10` ones, but will rather output `20`, because that is the `5` x `4`, the total number of `0` and `1`s in the array.

Comment: Why not try with == 1, increase value?

Comment: where is value initialized?

Comment: Ive got value initialized outside of the method. Also, if I change the condition to == 1, I get output of 0, which is also not correct as there are 1s in there.

Comment: You must reset `value` to 0 every time the method is called. Otherwise, you are continuously adding to `value` each time you call the method. I suggest you initialize `value = 0` inside your method, since it has no real "value" outside of the method.

Comment: Going from everything counting to nothing counting by changing to `== 1` is strange behavior.  Probably something wrong with the logic of checking for a `1`

Comment: @ryanyuyu would you mind explaining what you just meant to say, because I am finding it difficult to find a point in the sentance o.O

Comment: Sure @Fruloops.  My guess is that flipping your logic from `!= 0` to `== 1` also changed your output from minimum (0) to maximum (20).  I thought that was strange, and perhaps indicative of something wrong with the code that compared the data, or maybe the data itself.  Just a thought.

Comment: @ryanyuyu ye thx for this :) i went to check with with some different values and i have a feeling the array i create might have wrong values inside. Will check that thing out :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Initialize count to zero at the beginning before the loop,

```
public static int finding1s (int array[][]){
    int count = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++){
        for ( int j =0; j < array[i].length; j++){
             if (array[i][j] != 0){
                count++;
            }
        }
    }
    return count;
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    int[][] array = { { 0, 1, 0, 0 }, { 1, 0, 0, 0 }, { 0, 0, 1, 0 },
            { 1, 1, 0, 1 }, { 1, 1, 1, 1 } };
    System.out.println(finding1s(array));
}
```

Output is

```
10
```

Your `value` must not be zero (in fact, it must be 10) before your loop.

Answer (score 3):

Your method doesn't initialize `value` to `0`, nor does it declare it, so I must assume `value` is some `static` variable initialized elsewhere.

Now, if you call your method twice, without resetting `value` in between the calls, you'll get a result which is twice the expected result.